# How to make up arrow key display a multi-line command?

Tags: linux, ksh, putty

I just executed the below command in the terminal:

```
$ while read i
> do
> echo $i
> done
4
4
```

But when I tried to rerun the command using up arrow history feature, I am getting only partial command like below:

```
$ while read i
```

How to print whole while loop using up arrow in KSH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line editing in the original ksh is quite limited. You may want to use one of its "clones" like zsh¹ or bash instead.

For ksh93, I find that if you use the `vi` editing mode (`ksh -o vi`) as opposed to the `emacs` or `gmacs` one, then recalling multiline commands does *work*, though the newline characters are rendered as `^J`. That's also what you get with `pdksh` and its derivatives in all editing modes.

Note that you can also enter those newline characters with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> for that multi-line code to be entered on one line and then be able to recall it later even in `emacs` mode.

Another option is to use `fc` to edit the previous line in a real text editor:

```
fc while
```

Would call your preferred editor (in `$FCEDIT`, defaults to `ex` on my system) on the last (possibly multiline) command line that contained `while`. And then run it after you save and exit in the editor.

---

<sup>¹ `zsh` also has a `ksh` emulation mode that makes it behave more closely to `ksh` in case there are some `ksh` behaviours you do rely on (entered with `emulate ksh` or when invoking `zsh` as `ksh`)</sup>

Comment: wow thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. set -o vi option worked for recalling the multi-line command. I do not have the option of changing the shell to zsh as I have to work on the shell which is available on the remote machine. My FCEDIT was set to ed. And I was getting the error "$ fc
ksh: hist[1]: ed: not found [No such file or directory]
" Thanks for your $FCEDIT suggestion, I changed it to vi and now it is working like a charm. Up-voting and accepting this as answer. Thanks again for taking time to provide the detailed explanation. It helped me a lot :)